# How to Load a UI from Another UI (Redirection)

Tags: google-apps-script

I may be thinking about this the wrong way... but I have 2 different UIs built using UiApp;

**Part 1: the "Project Index UI"** which holds a list of all approved/pending projects.

- I have unique IDs for each project, with a row of information in another Spreadsheet that correlates to each ID.

**Example**: Project ID 20857 really points to row 4 in "Project Spreadsheet".

**Part 2: the "Project Details UI"** which is essentially an interface for editing the values in the Spreadsheet and updating calendar events with the new information.

---

The goal is to give my boss an index of all projects that are currently in the system. Then, as he wants, he can click on a project ID to load another UI that presents the information for that ID.

**So**: I was thinking about having the Project Name as an anchor, where the ID is embedded such as:

`var anchor = app.createAnchor("Some Project", "https://sites.google.com/site/mySite/asdf&ID=20857");`

Where `asdf` is the page where the "Project Details UI" is located. Then I would parse the URL to get the ID, and load the information into the Project Details UI that way.

---

What I'm thinking is that this is **way** too complicated, and that there is an easier way to accomplish this but I'm just not sure.

Is there a better method for generating a new UI with specific data obtained through a "link" of some sort in the original UI?

**Solution**: [TabPanel](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/tab-panel) with 2 tabs - each ID acts as a reference to a row of information in a Spreadsheet. When a button is clicked, a `serverHandler` invokes a function with that ID as a parameter, which fills the second tab with information for that ID.

Below are two illustrations of the UIs and how they should function:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have them written already and dont want to change much, it will work ok but it might be a bit slow, as each link click opens a new tab which loads the site and 2nd apps script which can be slow.
If you want something faster and a more streamlined interface you should change your code so you can load the 2nd gui inside the 1st one, for example use a stackpanel or a list that expands when you click it and put inside the 2nd ui. For this you need to merge both projects sources.

Comment: I actually haven't written either GUI yet. I wanted to get an idea of how I could generate a second UI from the first, after something like a *link click*. However, I've only designed 1 UI (not related to this) so far, and the only kind of "reloading" operation I did on it was erasing field values after a button click. I know how the `event handlers` work, but I'm not sure how to generate a completely different UI after an `Anchor` click, for example. I could probably attach the ID to the handler easily, but generating a new UI from there (and replacing the old on the same page) - I'm lost...

Comment: I guess that after reading the Docs on UiApp a bit more and looking at the different panel types, I'm understanding a bit more how they work. So here's a more specific question - if I have a `TabPanel` that has 2 tabs - the first with the `Index` page as described, and the second with the `Details` page as described, how can I have an `Anchor` or some other method of "communication" between them wherein if I click an element (`Anchor` or `Button` for example) in the `Index` tab, that it fills the `Details` tab with specific information for that item that I clicked?

Comment: whatever you use as the click element, use a server click handler on it. from the handler you fill the details pane. you will find more UI flexibility with htmlService instead of uiService

Comment: Okay that's what I was thinking. As for HTMLService - I know nothing about HTML. I wanted to use it because I know it's a souped-up version of UiApp, but I don't have enough time to learn it to implement it before the semester ends at my university and I leave for France. I will likely have time to redesign the entire system *after* I have a functional version that my boss can use while I'm away. Thank you for the suggestion though :)

Comment: @Chris, you can eventually have a look at this old version of an app build in uiApp that uses "false tabs" build with buttons  but still interresting as it works in a single uiApp instance code : https://script.google.com/d/1aL_y6ZqrfqrzhDZ4yzxM9Ax5hGi9KOHR0ltZ-7gVOTpQCDXV9zY3Ka_Y/edit?usp=sharing  exec : https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxquizfGo85vdeaN7_qss2-LY--UxSLFFeF5ML5rXPWZfrX9oNt/exec

Comment: @Sergeinsas, thanks, I'll take a look at it more closely tomorrow night. First glance, it looks very educational! Good thing I know French otherwise it might be hard to decipher ;)