# Connecting UI Elements in Google Apps Script (TabPanel - UiApp)

Tags: google-apps-script

I've already asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036597/how-to-load-a-ui-from-another-ui-redirection), but I really can't figure out how to connect these elements together. I'm still not very good with `Handlers`, and I guess my question is:

**How can I access UI Widgets (and their children) while outside of the doGet() function?**

My use case is this: I have a list of projects/IDs. I have all the data I want based on the ID that will populate the *Project Details* tab of this application. I created 'unique' `Button`s for each of these Projects, and threw them into a `Grid`. Now, I want to generate the *Project Details* (`detailPanel`) `Widget`s specifically for each `Button` if/when it is clicked.

I have the Project ID attached to each `Button` (uniquely) through a `Hidden`, but I can't seem to attach the *Project Details* tab (`detailPanel`) to the `Button` so that, when clicked, I can set the values for the `TextBox`, `DateBox`, `ListBox`, etc. `Widget`s of the `detailPanel`.

I think I'm missing something obvious about this. I want to **avoid attaching each child Widget of the `detailPanel` as a `callbackElement` of the `Button` *at all costs***. There are around 40 elements (I've lost count), and it seems really inefficient. I'm almost sure that if I can add one `Widget` as a callback element, that I get access to all *child* `Widget`s. But I tried, and that doesn't seem to be the case.

Here is the link to the public [UiApp](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyZhqfOCIPOgAhhG0qwoxH8hBNajldwbRTifQUwUHn09pdNUVcz/exec), which shows the UI. And the sister [Script Project (uneditable)](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyZhqfOCIPOgAhhG0qwoxH8hBNajldwbRTifQUwUHn09pdNUVcz/edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to add callback elements that you will write to, callback elements are only for reading their data. If the detailspanel id is dynamic have a hidden that has its id stored inside and pass it to the handler. from your handler you getelementbyid and set its data.

Comment: So my `detailPanel` has embedded elements: 4 `VerticalPanel`s that all contain `Grid`s. I have the `detailsPanel` (`VeriticalPanel`) stored in a variable in the `fillDetails` function. However, I'm not sure how to get access to the child widgets of that panel (the 4 embedded panels, grids, etc.). The `detailPanel` ID is not dynamic, it's static (`"detailPanel"`). Since I don't seem to have direct access to its children, do I need to *get all Widgets by ID* in the `fillDetails` function to have access to them?

Comment: Yes you do... but you should give them IDs that you can easily (re)build in a loop:  something like ele0, ele1, ele2... so that in a loop you do "ele"+n to get it  ... do the same for the widgets names and the values will be easy to retrieve as well using e.parameter["ele"+n].

Comment: Ahh, that's what I figured. I was hoping have some kind of element chain like `detailPanel.VerticalPanel.Grid.DateBox`, but that would be too weird now that I think about it. I'm wondering though - this is a project that will likely need to be maintained by another person in the future. Would it be a good idea to have Widgets named like `"widgetXX"`? Sure, they're easier to manage that way by using loops instead of 40 lines of code to identify them uniquely, but that's also a lot harder to read/ understand what they're doing.